# Getting model value in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My view contains a model property and a submit button,

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "txtLgnPasswordReset", @class = "form-control avoid-copy-paste" })
<div class="row vert-offset-top-2 vert-offset-bottom-2">
      <div class="col-md-2">
          <button id="submitSave" type="submit" class="btn btnColor ladda-button">Save</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

On click of Login button I need the password value in jquery, I've tried this which doesn't help..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var password = $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").html();
    $("#submitSave").on("click", function() {
        alert(password);
        $.ajax({

        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$.fn.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method instead of `$.fn.html()`

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

*Script*

```
var password = $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val();
alert(password);
```

Comment: @MichaelPhilips, Then use `var password = $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val();`

Comment: @MichaelPhilips, Since you are new you should consider accepting the answer which helped you most not necessarily mine. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

also from your above code it's look like that you are trying to submit the form using ajax post with button type `submit`, so you also need to change following in your code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var password = $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val(); // instead of html(), use val()
    $("#submitSave").on("click", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the submit and you can add your additional code below and then send it through ajax.
        alert(password);
        $.ajax({

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var password = $("#txtLgnPasswordReset").val();
  $("#submitSave").on("click", function() {
    alert(password);
    $.ajax({

    });
  });
});
```